# Is wp_deregister_script the best way to deal with unneeded plugins in a page?

Tags: plugins, css, performance

I use some "heavy duty" plugging, like syntaxhighlighter, GD star rating etc.
i create a de-register.php file which i use to  deregister scripts and styles whenever they are not used.

**Example:**

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 100 );
function my_deregister_styles() {

    if (is_home()) {
        wp_deregister_style('bbp-default');
        wp_dequeue_style('bbp-default');
        wp_deregister_style('bbp-default-rtl');
        wp_dequeue_style('bbp-default-rtl');

        wp_deregister_style('edd-styles');
        wp_dequeue_style('edd-styles');

        wp_deregister_style('onp-sociallocker');
        wp_dequeue_style('onp-sociallocker');
    }
}
```

In this page i have about 200 lines since i am de-registering the css and js files of 5 plugins (or so) when ever they are not being used.

For that end i created some checkbox metaboxes in each post where i can click and say "i use rating here" (for example).

**My question is.**
Is my way wrong? Does the whole process of using wp_deregister_style and wp_deregister_script defeats the purpose?

Does the actual use of those actions slows my site down? Is there a better way to only use plugins and the styles and scripts they come with when i need them and only then?

**I have of course read and searched** but couldn't find anything else.
Would love to hear of any solution you think might fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to activate a plugin only when it is necessary. There is a better option to do this. You can activate the whole plugin upon a certain action. I have provided a example code that will help you achieve what you are looking for and if you have any more queries you can put a comment. If it works for you can accept the answer.

```
function run_activate_plugin( $plugin ) {
     $current = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
     $plugin = plugin_basename( trim( $plugin ) );

         if ( !in_array( $plugin, $current ) ) {
           $current[] = $plugin;
           sort( $current );
           do_action( 'activate_plugin', trim( $plugin ) );
           update_option( 'active_plugins', $current );
           do_action( 'activate_' . trim( $plugin ) );
           do_action( 'activated_plugin', trim( $plugin) );
           } 

         return null;
       }
         run_activate_plugin( 'akismet/akismet.php' );
```

Comment: i have to do some testing ;) I am trying to lower the load time - and trying to asertaine the affect of de-registering stuff vs other solutions.

Comment: thanks for your input, its not what i what searching for but an intresting answer (and the only suggestion). Cheers, Sagive.